# react-bootstrap popover not showing (while tooltip is ok)

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

My Popover component is never shown.
Same code with Tooltip is ok (but I need a popover...)

My code :

```
<OverlayTrigger 
   placement="right" 
   trigger="hover" 
   key="overlay-1" 
   overlay={<Tooltip id="tooltip1">Test</Tooltip>}
 >
   <label className="col-1">Journée</label>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

this one is ok (tooltip) while the next is not working :

```
<OverlayTrigger 
     placement="right" 
     trigger="hover" 
     key="overlay-1"
     overlay={<Popover id="popover-basic" title="Popover right">Test</Popover>}
 >
   <label className="col-1">Journée</label>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Comment: add-on : "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8", "react-popper": "^1.3.3",

Comment: this should work, provided, you have to import Popover from react-bootstrap. `import { OverlayTrigger, Popover } from 'react-bootstrap';`